# Get current URI in Twig template

Tags: symfony, uri, twig

Does anybody know how to get the current URI in a Twig template?

I’ve read through the documentation and I’m unable to find the Twig function to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{{ app.request.uri }}
```

If you want to read it into a view variable:

```
{% set uri = app.request.uri %}
```

The `app` global view variable contains all sorts of useful shortcuts, such as `app.session` and `app.security.token.user`, that reference the services you might use in a controller.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where any documentation is for this global variable?

Comment: The only documentation I've ever found on it is in the file itself: `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables`