# Request uri twig - Event GA

Tags: symfony, google-analytics, twig, analytics

I have a small problem and a question. I've had fun with Twig, I have some themes and I would like to put in the GA event.

```
{% href = "{{clickUrl}}"
target = "_ blank"
{% if clickUrl | isNoFollowUrl%}
   rel = "nofollow"
{% endif%}
itemscope=""
itemtype = "http://schema.org/Offer"
onclick=" ga ('send', 'event', **'URL'**, '{{product.getTitle | raw}}');"
class =" MyClass">
```

Everything works fine, events in GA are counting, but my problem occurs when in Event Category I want to give URI / URL of a subpage - but I do not know how to do it - can you help me?

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881233/get-current-uri-in-twig-template

Comment: @damian0021 I reformatted your code. You have an addtional `{%` in front of the `href` which doesn't see right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current URI in Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881233/get-current-uri-in-twig-template)